# Post image data instead of image url in fabric js

Tags: imagemagick, fabricjs

I have implemented the Drag n Drop image, now the issue is when i am converting canvas data as toSVG and send it to server it includes the image URL instead of image data.

When user upload the file then i am using below method:

```
     //Add photo in canvas
    document.getElementById('add_image').addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        var file = e.target.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (f) {
            var data = f.target.result;
            fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function (img) {
                var oImg = img.set({
                    left: 0,
                    top: 0,
                    angle: 0,
                    border: '#000',
                    stroke: '#F0F0F0', //<-- set this
                    strokeWidth: 0, //<-- set this
                    fill: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
                }).scale(0.2);
                canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
                canvas.moveTo(oImg, z_index);
                z_index = z_index + 1;
                //var a = canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
                var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({
                    format: 'png',
                    quality: 1
                });
            });
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        $(this).val('');
    });
```

then it sends the data as below:

> < image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="data:image/gif;base64,..." x="-100" y="-100" style="stroke: rgb(240,240,240); stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-opacity: 0; fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" width="200" height="200">

Here ... contains base64 data.

If image is uploaded using Drag n Drop then i am using below method:

```
var new_image = new fabric.Image(obj, {
    width: obj.naturalWidth,
    height: obj.naturalHeight,
    scaleX: setImageWidth/obj.naturalWidth,        
    scaleY: setImageHeight/obj.naturalHeight,
    // Set the center of the new object based on the event coordinates relative
    // to the canvas container.
    left: e.layerX,
    top: e.layerY,
    id: 'verified_image'
});
canvas.add(new_image);
canvas.renderAll();
```

which sends the data as below:

> < image id="verified_image" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://localhost/lynkus/uploads/userprofile/verified_image.png" x="-256" y="-256" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" width="512" height="512">

So both type of image uploading is working fine but the issue is i am trying to generate the png file using above svg. So system is able to create png for 1st option but not for 2nd option as its have a URL.
So is there a way to send data as base 64 instead of image url in drag n drop option?

http://jsfiddle.net/durga598/w8kkc/414/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function handleDrop(e) {
  // this / e.target is current target element.
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.stopPropagation) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // stops the browser from redirecting.
  }

  var img = document.querySelector('#images img.img_dragging');

  var setImageWidth = 100,
    setImageHeight = 100;
  var imgObj = new Image();
  imgObj.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
  imgObj.onload = function(oImg) {
    var tempCanvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
    var tempCtx = tempCanvas.getContext('2d');
    var height = tempCanvas.height = this.naturalHeight;
    var width = tempCanvas.width = this.naturalWidth;
    tempCtx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    var dataURL = tempCanvas.toDataURL();
    fabric.Image.fromURL(dataURL, function(img) {
      img.set({
        width: width,
        height: height,
        scaleX: setImageWidth / width,
        scaleY: setImageHeight / height,
        left: e.layerX,
        top: e.layerY,
      })
      canvas.add(img);
    })
  }
  imgObj.src = img.src;
  return false;
}
```

You need to create an image object and convert that to base64 data using toDataURL of canvas element. Then use `fabric.Image.fromURL` to add that image data to fabric canvas. Here is updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/durga598/w8kkc/416/).

Comment: Out of this question's scope: how do one create printable svg (which supports all fonts, background etc.)  on server side?

Comment: @DS9 never came across that, if I will find anything will let you know ;)

Comment: Has anyone had any issues with Safari when call fromURL(), the callback seems to fire a bit too early? I had to includea setTimeout of 10 to fix this.